# Get-MessageTrace Need a Powershell command to show inbound mail to 1 mailbox grouped by date Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, office365api

I'm figuring I'll use the Get-MessageTrace, but I need to show inbound mail for 1 mailbox, grouped by date. This is for Exchange 365.

```
Date         Count
____         ____
8/22/2018    45
8/23/2018    15
8/24/2018    22
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to check the amount of emails received for a particular email account between a certain date period.

Please try the code below:

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell" -Credential $creds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
$messages = Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress address@example.com -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -EndDate (Get-Date)
$messages.Count
```

For more information, please review the following link: [Office 365 mailbox recieved mail count](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1986117-office-365-mailbox-recieved-mail-count)